# Java Linked List Recursive Insertion

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I need a recursive method to insert element into a linked list. When  a new element is inserted into the list, the descending ordering of list elements must be maintained. This means that the inserted element values must be in a descending order. The skeleton of the program is

```
public static ListElement InsertList(ListElement head, ListElement elem) {

}
```

The implementation of the ListElement is

```
public class ListElement {
int value
ListElement next;
}
```

Please stick to the node class provided. Only InsertList class needs to be written. Use RECURSION. It should be less than 10 lines of codes. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your code for InsertList and the error you are seeing ?

Comment: So, you're asking us to do your homework?

Answer (score 1):

U need to try first and then ask the community for help if you are stuck. Stackoverflow is not your homework assignment solution maker.